# Why is the SI unit of Magnetic Pole Strength Ampere-meter?

Tags: electromagnetism, dimensional-analysis, si-units

Till now I was silent because I thought the SI unit of pole strength to be Ampere-Second and due to everything in analogy with electrostatic, it was ok, but when I looked closely, it changed to Ampere Meter, so my question is the expression at that time,**WHY?**

Comment: Where did you come across these units?  As there are no known magnetic poles there is  more that one way to specify pole strength.

Comment: My school's textbook, :').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: **there are no magnetic (mono)poles**. As such, specifying units for quantities that don't exist is a rather futile (and not particularly well-defined) exercise.

That said, *if* there were magnetic monopoles, then you would expect that if you had two opposite magnetic monopoles of strength $\pm m$ separated by a distance $d$, the result would be a magnetic dipole of strength $\mu = md$.

And, luckily, magnetic dipoles do exist (they are basically loops of electric current), and their units are known (specifically, the units are $\rm A\:m^2$ and the dimensions are $[\mu]=[IL^2]$, corresponding to the strength of the electric current times the area of the loop).

This fixes the dimensions of $m$, since we would require $[md]=[IL^2]$ and therefore $[m]=[IL]$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I never came across this quantity, but I read that one can derive the units of pole strength by assuming that the magnetic force to have a form similar to Coulomb's Law:
\begin{equation}
F = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}
\end{equation}
where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the magnetic (mono)poles and act as the charges in Coulomb's Law.

As we know that:

- The force $F$ is measured in newton ($\mathrm{N}$);
- The permeability $\mu_0$ is measured in newton per ampere squared ($\mathrm{N} / \mathrm{A}^2$);
- The distance $r$ is measured in meters ($\mathrm{m}$);

we must have that $m_1$ and $m_2$ have the units of ampere times meter ($\mathrm{A}\cdot\mathrm{m}$) to guarantee the dimensional soundness of the equation.
Indeed, from the previous equation
\begin{equation}
[\mathrm{N}] = \frac{[\mathrm{N}]}{[\mathrm{A}]^2}\frac{[m_1] [m_2]}{[\mathrm{m}]^2}\quad\rightarrow\quad [m_1] = [m_1] = [\mathrm{A}]\cdot[\mathrm{m}]
\end{equation}

**PS.** recall that the Coulomb's law reads $F = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I started with this but I was told that unit of permeability to be Henry/Meter, but I wasn't able to convert from that.

Comment: @gud_fr_nthng Henry is volt * second / ampere = (joule / coulomb) * second / ampere = newton * meter / ampere²

Comment: Thank you for giving time to this.

Comment: The force equation you cite gives an approximate value for the force only if , r, is large when compared to the diameter of the poles.